# pgfplots: Swap colors of predefined cycle list (colorbrewer)

Tags: pgfplots, color

I would like to use the `colorbrewer` cycle list `Set1-5` in pgfplots.
This usually starts with a red color, followed by a blue color. However, I would like to use the blue color as my first color and red as the second, so basically swap the first two colors.

I know, I could do this for one specific plot, but I would like to do this for my entire document, e.g. by defining a new cycle list based on `Set1-5`.

Is there a way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    every axis/.append style={grid, width=0.98\textwidth, height=8cm},
    grid style={densely dotted, thick},
    every axis plot/.append style={thick},
    label style={},
    ticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep = {},
        /tikz/.cd
    },  
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos={north east},
}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Set1-5}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to do this is to create new `cycle list` where you switch the first to colors by making use of the `indices of colormap` feature.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
    \pgfplotsset{
        cycle list/Set1-5,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------
        % (this is just to make things simple)
        % copied from the manual
        cycle from colormap manual style/.style={
            x=3cm,y=10pt,ytick=\empty,
            colorbar style={x=,y=,ytick=\empty},
            point meta min=0,point meta max=1,
            stack plots=y,
            y dir=reverse,colorbar style={y dir=reverse},
            every axis plot/.style={line width=2pt},
            legend entries={0,...,20},
            legend pos=outer north east,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        cycle from colormap manual style,
        cycle list={[indices of colormap={1,0,2,3,4 of Set1-5}]},
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This `indices of colormap` is exactly what I needed, thank you! I decided to define a new cycle list with `\pgfplotsset{cycle list/.define={Default1-5}{[indices of colormap={1,0,2,3,4 of Set1-5}]},}`